# Error: Could not find or load main class. Command Prompt

Tags: java, class, find, load

I am trying my had at java programming and I made a HelloWorld program and if you need the code its right here:

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args){        
         System.out.println("helloworld");
     }
}
```

It compiled without error and whenever I try to run it from the command prompt it says:

> "Error: Could not find or load main class".

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have the jre 1.8.0_45 and jdk 1.7.0_71.

Comment: What command are you typing into the command prompt to run the program?

Comment: I navigate to the location of the .class and type "java helloworld.class"

Comment: What is the file name of the class file?  It should be `main`.  Also you don't need `.class` when you're executing the class. You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Okay, i changed the file name and its still doing the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment

> I navigate to the location of the .class and type "java
>   helloworld.class" –  Takdm

you don't `.class` when you run the program. Just do

```
java helloworld
```

Comment: i did and i also renamed it to main also but its still giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

First- the file name and the class name must be identical.
Then compile your program using `javac FileName.java` command
To run your program try- `java -cp . ClassName`
Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding . to CLASSPATH variable in Environment variables solved my problem!!

Java searches for the classes in the paths mentioned in the CLASSPATH variable if you don't add . there, it won't search for classes in the current working directory!!!

Go to Control panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced

Click Environment Variables

If the CLASSPATH variable is present under User variables, add '.' separated by a semicolon. For example, if Java is installed in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin , CLASSPATH will be

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;.;
```

Click OK.